# yum + dose yum support resume installing

Tags: linux, networking, yum

I want to share the following problem

when yum install & download heavy packages , this take time ( couple min )
regarding to that . I want to explain the following problem:

when suddenly network can be unreachable , for example for few seconds or less
then , dose yum can do resume from the point that its start to install ?